# How to count similar groups of items in a list using Excel?

Tags: excel, grouping, countif

I thought I was getting pretty good with Excel sumifs/maxifs/minifs/countifs but I am stuck on this one. I am trying to count the number of grouped elements in a list, using a concise formula in a single column (manually copied down the array range) preferably using one of my favorites mentioned above and without using Excel's annoying array function where you have to press Ctrl/Shift/Enter, and without using VBA. I illustrate and explain the desired outputs of block group counts below in yellow. Any ideas for a formula that does this?

The `<< Formula` columns are only illustrating countifs() using a single condition and multiple conditions, respectively.

[image]

Comment: Try my new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a spill range array (same as ctl shift enter) without pressing it.  Hopefully you have that functionality.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(A2,UNIQUE(FILTER(A$2:A2&B$2:B2,A$2:A2<>"")))))
```

[See example on Google Sheets but will work on excel.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/158v-LSDdo2KSR63U8VXW4QAL12kpcxyIpbM0wiUBh4o/)

Comment: This will not spill results automatically. You need to drag down formula to each cell. Also OP on Excel not on google-sheet.

Comment: @Harun24hr Thanks, I didn't realize `countif` could not handle an array in Excel (weird). I can use `Sumproduct` for practically the same and it works in Excel. I do see the post asking for a  *single cell* yet, the post also said no arrays, so I'm assuming the drag down is acceptable. `ByRow` is cool but that function isn't available to everyone yet (including my work machine). I may tinker with making a dynamic array later, though I'm not sure how that could be done.

Comment: Hi, works great. When I said "single cell" in the OP, I meant I would like to use a "single column" and copy the formula down. I'll edit the OP accordingly. I didn't even know there was a "single cell" option! But the copying down, in one column, was what I was after. And I have all this functionality btw. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Try below formula-

```
=BYROW(B3:B17,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--((UNIQUE(FILTER(C3:C17,(B3:B17=x)*(ROW(C3:C17)<=ROW(x)))))<>""))))
```

[image]

Comment: In 2024 this will probably be the better answer as the functionality should be available to all.

Comment: @pgSystemTester BYROW() is available to all O365 users.

Comment: my subscription/version is up to date and does not have it (Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20648)